# Hide back button bar of android mobile while playing game

Tags: unity, 2d

I just want to hide back button bar of android mobile while playing the game.

I tried to make it close by pressing back button,it getting close but its always visible.
please help..

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "hide back button bar" ? How can you hide a button from a mobile phone exactly ? and what is the "bar" referring to ?

Comment: In Unity, if you go Edit > Project Settings > Player, under Settings for Android, try making sure Status Bar Hidden is ticked.

Comment: @Chris Yah i ckecked it out,status bar hidden is ticked but still getting that bar while playing mode